# No route matches [POST] "/sessions/user" - When sign in/sign up - Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise, routes

Whenever I click the sign in or sign up button on my site, I receive this error:

Routing Error -- No route matches [POST]"/sessions/user"

[image: routing error]

Here is my routes file:

[image: routing error]

Here are my routes:

[image: routing error]

[image: routing error]

[image: routing error]

Any ideas as to why I am receiving this error?

Comment: have you modified the code on the devise forms; specifically, the destination URL?

Comment: I'm not sure. I don't remember. Where can I find out if I did?

Comment: in the devise forms - eg `/app/views/devise/registrations`

Comment: also, you don't need to define `resources :sessions`, and defining two `resources :users` blocks will overwrite each other - use only one.

Answer (score 0):

Devise uses it's own methods to generate routes, is it possible that `resources :sessions` is overriding the methods devise needs to exist? I'm almost positive devise defines a method called `new_session_path(resource_name, resource)`. Your `resources :sessions` may be stepping on Devise's toes so to speak.

EDIT

**I have just confirmed this by cloning devise and running `grep -R session_path .`**. You need to remove `resources :sessions` from your code, or scope it into a different namespace using `:as`.

```
resources :sessions, :as => 'sessions_that_dont_anger_devise'
#=> 
  new_sessions_that_dont_anger_devise_path
  sessions_that_dont_anger_devise_path
  ... etc.
```

Comment: this doesn't answer the question of why he is getting such an error.

Comment: Well when you request a route that doesn't exist, you get a Routing Error.

Comment: and where is he doing that, praytell?

Comment: I have edited my answer to improve completeness. I am very certain that I have answered the question at this point.

Comment: I think you're right. However, I tried removing resources :sessions before and it didn't work. How do I go about scoping it into a different namespace?

Comment: use `:as => 'other_namespace'`. I believe you will need to restart your app.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to post to user/sessions instead of sessions/user

Answer (score 0):

```
resources :users, only: [:show, :new, :create] do
member do
  get :following, :followers
end
```

end

Fixed by removing the first resources :users and stuffing it into this method.